# Advanced Custom Fields checkbox storing data in single string instead of array

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to get the checked boxes in my field in an array, but get_field of the checkbox field returns the values in an array of size 1 with the labels of the checked boxes in a single string, separated by ' | '.
I can't seem to figure out how to get ACF to give me an array.

So I want `get_field('checkboxes')'` to return this

```
Array ( [0] => checkbox1 [1] => checkbox2 [2] => checkbox3 )
```

But I'm getting this

```
Array ( [0] => checkbox1 | checkbox2 | checkbox3 )
```

I have the return format of the field set to Value, i've checked the ACF documentation for checkboxes and I'm doing exactly as it says but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

when set return is 'value' then your output will be:

```
$field = get_field_object('checkboxes');
$choices = $field['value'];

<?php if( $choices ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $choices as $checkbox): ?>
        <?php echo $field['choices'][ $checkbox]; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: under `$field['choices']` i get this array: `[choices] => Array ( [checkbox1] => checkbox1 [checkbox2] => checkbox2 [checkbox3] => checkbox3 [checkbox4] => checkbox4 )` with all the boxes, not only the checked ones.
I've found out that the problem only happens when i auto-fill the field from a form. If i fill out the post manually everything works as intended

Comment: thats because none are selected. it needs to be saved in the post